# Can I convert an IPA file to support a higher version of iOS?

Tags: ios

I bought my iPad 2 in 2012 which currently runs iOS 7. I have this amazing app through which I am able to download any video I find online. I was able to retrieve the IPA file through my iPad, but each time I try to transfer it to my iPhone 8 Plus running the latest iOS, on iTunes it says that the app I want to copy is not compatible with the higher iOS version on my iPhone.

When I try to use my iCloud back up from the iPad, it simply does not even show up in my apps. This app is not even in my purchases on the App Store with my Apple ID. I have tried using Cydia Impactor, CopyTrans Manager and iMazing, none of it has worked so far. Is there any way I can change this IPA file to support a higher version of iOS? I do not have a MacBook, I do not know if Xcode would even work with this but I am unable to use it if there is any solution on Windows I would love to try it.

Comment: No. The app tries to call functions that are not there or behave differently.

Comment: Okay thank you for your answer, would it be possible to mold the ipa file into a usable app on Xcode?

Comment: No you can't decompile It. your only chance is if you had the code and even then it would need changing see https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/70787/237

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way I can change this IPA file to support a higher version of iOS?

No, it is not possible to modify an IPA to run on a higher version of iOS. Also, it is not possible to reverse engineer an IPA using Xcode as it contains compiled code.

Comment: Reverse engineer is possible, but might need more specialized tools than Xcode :-)